# PHP spawn process

Tags: php

How can I spawn a process in a PHP page in order to start a program *that survives the execution time of the request*?

In other words, I want the page to have a normal lifetime (few milliseconds) but launch a program that keeps running on the server. Thanks

Comment: Here's [a helpful tutorial on this topic](http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/1/0) that I've referenced many times. You may have to get a few pages in to get specifically to process forking, but the whole bit is worth absorbing if you want to get into process management with php.

Comment: @rdlowrey that link is no longer valid

Comment: @rineez try [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140627231234/https://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/1/0)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php exec('nohup /usr/bin/my-command > /dev/null 2>&1 &'); ?>
```

This forks the sub-process into the background and writes all of the output into `/dev/null`. That way PHP continues executing the script as if there won't be any output it has to wait for.

Comment: what about windows? any equivalent?

Comment: I don't know about Windows. I am Linux User.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use CRON if you need to start a process on a time basis.

Comment: I don't the the original poster wants to know how to start a program at a certain time, which is what CRON does. Rather, the question is about having a web page written in PHP start a background process whenever someone goes to that page. That doesn't necessarily happen at a certain time.